# Build a Map from a Set in Groovy

Tags: collections, dictionary, groovy, set

We have the following legacy data structure of Parent and Child objects of the same type

```
Parent1(name1,code1,null)
  Child11(name11,code11,Parent1)
  Child12(name12,code12,Parent1)
Parent2(name2,code2,null)
  Child21(name21,code21,Parent2)
  Child22(name22,code22,Parent2)
etc.
```

We have a legacy service available that returns a Set of all the Child objects. The Parent objects are not returned but we can call a getParent() getter for a particular Child in the Set to get its Parent. We need to call this service from a Groovy class, and afterwards build a Map that reflects the original structure

```
def dataMap = [data:[["name":"name1", "code":"code1", 
                         "children":[["name":"name11", "code":"code11"], 
                                     ["name":"name12", "code":"code12"]]], 
                    ["name":"name2", "code":"code2", 
                         "children":[["name":"name21", "code":"code21"], 
                                     ["name":"name22", "code":"code22"]]]]]
```

So basically the Map keys are the Parent (name,code) pairs, and the values are Lists of the respective Child objects' (name,code) pairs (the Map will be rendered to JSON afterwards actually)

Being quite novice to Groovy I could probably solve this using Java syntax, but I wonder whether there is a more concise solution using Groovy specific features? Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: Can the child nodes have children?  (ie: can the tree be deeper than one level).  Also, what items do you have?  Do you just have a list containing all the children and parents?

Comment: 1. No, the children have no other children, so there can be no further level in the tree 2. I am not sure whether I understand this question correctly, but we have only the mentioned legacy method available, that returns a Set of all the Child objects in the tree; we have to loop on that Set and build the Map by using childXY.getParent() to determine the Parent for the particular Child

Comment: So you have a method that returns all the leaf nodes of a one-deep tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I understand it, this is the setup you have:

```
import groovy.transform.*
import groovy.json.*

@TupleConstructor(includeFields=true)
class Node {
    String name
    String code
    private Node parent

    String getParentName() { parent?.name }
    String getParentCode() { parent?.code }
}

def parent1 = new Node( 'name1',  'code1',  null )
def child11 = new Node( 'name11', 'code11', parent1 )
def child12 = new Node( 'name12', 'code12', parent1 )
def parent2 = new Node( 'name2',  'code2',  null )
def child21 = new Node( 'name21', 'code21', parent2 )
def child22 = new Node( 'name22', 'code22', parent2 )

// This is returned by a call to your API
Set nodes = [ child11, child12, child21, child22 ]
```

Then, you can do the following (there are probably other routes, and this will only work for single depth trees)

```
// Get a set of parent nodes
Set parents = nodes.collect { [ name:it.parentName, code:it.parentCode ] }

// Utility closure to return a name and code in a Map
def format = { Node n ->
    [ name: n.name, code: n.code ]
}

// Collect the formatted parents with their formatted children into a Map
def dataMap = [ data:parents.collect { p ->
    p + [ children:nodes.findAll { 
                       it.parentName == p.name && it.parentCode == p.code
                   }.collect { format( it ) } ]
} ]

// Print the JSON representation of this
println new JsonBuilder( dataMap ).toPrettyString()
```

That should print:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "name2",
            "code": "code2",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "name21",
                    "code": "code21"
                },
                {
                    "name": "name22",
                    "code": "code22"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "name1",
            "code": "code1",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "name11",
                    "code": "code11"
                },
                {
                    "name": "name12",
                    "code": "code12"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I played around with the code, and I think I got the main idea about the logic. However, having a check on the legacy API (which is in Java), it seems that there is actually no getParent() method, but instead getParentName() and getParentCode() only. This apparently seems to imply that .parent cannot be referred as above. Could you possibly modify the code according to this? Thank you in advance and apologize for not being precise in the original question.

Comment: @hammerfest try that :-)

Comment: Got it, thank you once again; the problem with this seems to be that you have also modified the Node structure, so for you it.parentName and it.parentCode are valid syntax. However in our legacy Node is a POJO with fields String name, String code and Node parent (as it was used correctly in your original answer) and methods getName(), getCode(), getParentName() and getParentCode() which seems to deny using it.parentName and it.parentCode :/

Comment: Odd, it should still work as Groovy should just call the getter for property access...  What error do you get?

Comment: @hammerfest updated again, to hopefully more closely model your situation

Comment: I played around some with the code and wrote some unit tests to debug; there has been some syntax problem from my behalf which had to be fixed, though Greclipse keeps the it. and p. references underlined, now it seems to run without problems and produces the expected result. Thanks for your high quality and detailed help.